# Why doesn't the value of instance variable persist?

Tags: c++

I have created a queue on the `MP1Node` class, and add to it from the `recvCallBack` method. My goal was to use this queue to send the messages after having figured out the `member_list` from the `nodeLoopOps`. However, the elements in this queue, let's call it `msgQ`, are getting lost as soon as `checkMessages` returns. I don't understand why this is happening. Is `checkMessages()` being executed in a new instance of the class? Why wouldn't `msgQ` persist and how can I make it persist?

```
void MP1Node::nodeLoop() {

    // Check my messages
    checkMessages();

   // NOTE: msgQ size == 0 here

    return;
}

void MP1Node::checkMessages() {
    void *ptr;
    int size;

    ...
    recvCallBack((char *)ptr, size);    
    ...

    // NOTE: msgQ size == 1 here

    return;
}

bool MP1Node::recvCallBack(char *data, int size ) {
  ...
  scheduleMessage(newMsg);
  ...
}

void MP1Node::scheduleMessage(Message m){
    msgQ.emplace(m);
}

class MP1Node {
private:
  queue<Message> msgQ;
}
```

Comment: `However, the elements in this queue, let's call it msgQ, are getting lost as soon as checkMessages returns`  How did you confirm that the value is getting lost?

Comment: The size of the `msgQ` is zero after `checkMessages()` returns.

Comment: Are you outputting this information in some way, or using the debugger to verify this?  If you're using the debugger, misuse of the debugger can give you a false information.  Also, what type is this "queue", `std::queue`?  Also, where is it declared?

Comment: Yes, I'm printing the size of the queue to `cout` to verify it. The queue is from the standard library.

Comment: If it's `std::queue`, then you should post more code.  If the queue is a member variable, then the size cannot change, unless your program has corrupted memory in some way.  A `std::queue` and all the other STL containers store *copies* of the values, so it doesn't matter if the value you pushed into the queue is local.  The worse that could (or should) happen is if you are storing pointers to local variables -- the size of the queue will stay the same, only the item in the queue won't be valid on return.

Comment: Just to add, a queue just doesn't change size like that, unless your code is multithreaded and the queue is being accessed by another thread.  Is your code multithreaded?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell for sure from the skeleton code provided.

But this part is a bit suspicious:
The queue is defined to hold objects of type Message. newMsg appears to be a local variable created in method recvCallBack(). scheduleMessage() is called with that Message instance at which point the message object is enqueued. However, because the Message instance newMsg has local scope, it goes out of scope when recvCallBack() returns.

At this point I may expect the queue to contain garbage, but perhaps instead it's exhibiting as empty.

Comment: I think you're exactly right! I'm a C++ noob. Can you explain how I might add a local variable's value to a queue as in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the answer.  If the queue is a member variable, adding a local variable should not affect the queue's size on return.  The queue may have an invalid item in it on return (if the address of the local variable were stored in the queue), but the size of the queue would remain (in this case) 1.